ROS2 Humble Installation Environment Setup Issue - ros2: command not found
I am using Untuntu 22.04 in WSL trying to install ROS2 Humble.
After following the tutorial in ROS2 website, I am stuck with the setting up the environment.
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash
I am unable to run ROS2 with the command ros2 even after I have sourced setup.bash.
I have double checked I am using Bash shell.
Found no solutions on the internet.
My last resort was ChatGPT, it said "ros2 executable is not present in the /opt/ros/humble/bin directory"
Anyone know what's the issue and how to solve it.
Greatly appreciated!

Guys I used the source installation https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Installation/Alternatives/Ubuntu-Development-Setup.html instead of binary and successful. It should be ~/ros2_humble/install/local_setup.bash instead when setting up the environment.
But if you open a new terminal and run ros2 you will still get ros2 command not found. You will have to do the following:

Open shell configuration file: nano ~/.bashrc, it opens a text editor
Add this line at the end of the line: source /<path to ros2>/install/setup.bash
Save the changes with Ctrl+O and press Enter
After saving the changes, either open a new terminal window or run the following command to apply the changes to your current terminal session:
source ~/.bashrc
Close terminal and re-open again, try ros2 again

Let me know if the above works for you or I have any mistakes.
Hope it helps!

This worked for me:
sudo apt update
sudo apt install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros2/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) main"
sudo apt update

to remove the old
sudo rm /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ros-archive-keyring.gpg

then add it with
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ros-archive-keyring.gpg

finally
sudo apt update

After all of this try
sudo apt install ros-humble-desktop-full

If it installs in 1 minute then it's wrong, it's supposed to take at least 8 or 10 minutes. Once it's installed properly then you can finally
source /opt/ros/humble/setup.bash

